# cell border showing on border:none td

Tags: html, css, border, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="clearCell" colspan="2">borderless</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="borderedRow">
        <td>bordered</td>
        <td class="clearCell">borderless</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with the following css:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.borderedRow td {
     border: solid black 1px; 
}
td.clearCell {
    border: none;
}
```

This produces a top border on the borderless cell. Why?
For ease I have this as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1g4kfxjx/1/

Update: Oddly the border can be removed by changing the colspan on the cell in the previous row. That doesn't explain why the border shows up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't happen in Internet Explorer or Firefox...looks like a "Chrome bug" to me.